# C: Quicksort linked list

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm supposed to write a program, that reads passwords and numbers from a file, e.g. `jskskfj 128938`, puts them in a linked list and sorts them using quicksort. The file contains 100 entries. I already managed to read it into a linked list, that works fine. However, I'm having trouble with the quicksort and partition functions, since most tutorials online use swapping instead of moving, however I'm supposed to move the numbers smaller than the pivot into a new list, same with the bigger numbers and concatenate them in the end. So far, here are my efforts:

Main:

```
#include "blatt10.h"

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Nutzung: %s <Dateiname>\n", args[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    list mylist;
    init_list(&mylist);
    read_data(args[1], &mylist);
    qsort_list(&mylist);
    printf("Sortierte Liste:\n");
    print_list(&mylist);
    free_list(&mylist);
    return 0;
}
```

Help-file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct passwort passwort;

struct passwort {
    char name[100];
    int anzahl;
};

typedef struct list_element list_element;

struct list_element {
    passwort data;
    list_element *next;
};

typedef struct list list;

struct list {
    list_element *first;
    list_element *last;
};

void init_list(list *mylist);
void insert_front(list_element *le, list *mylist);
void free_list(list *mylist);
void read_data(char *filename, list *mylist);
list_element *partition(list *input, list *left, list *right);
void qsort_list(list *mylist);
void print_list(list *mylist);
```

My code (I only copied the necessary functions, not all of them):

```
void init_list(list *mylist) {    
    mylist->first = NULL;
    mylist->last = NULL;

}

void insert_front(list_element *le, list *mylist) {
    if (mylist->first == NULL) {
        mylist->first = le;
        mylist->last = le;
    } else {
        le->next = mylist->first;
        mylist->first = le; 
    }
}

list_element *partition(list *input, list *left, list *right) {
    list_element *pivot = malloc(sizeof(list_element));
    pivot->next = NULL;

    if (input->first != NULL) {
        input->first = pivot;
    } else {
        printf("Liste leer!\n");
    }

    if (input->first == input->last) {
        return (input->first);
    }

    list_element *tmp = input->first;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (tmp->data.anzahl >= pivot->data.anzahl) {
            insert_front(tmp, right);
            printf("%s\n", tmp->data.name);
        } else {
            insert_front(tmp, left);
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return (pivot);
}

void qsort_list(list *mylist) {
    int length = 100;
    if (length > 1) {
        list *A;
        init_list(A);
        list *B;
        init_list(B);
        list_element *pivot;
        pivot = partition(mylist, A, B);
        qsort_list(A);
        qsort_list(B);
        mylist = concatenate(A, pivot, B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to write quicksort that works on lists is asking for trouble... Don't do that unless you must.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Linked lists and mergesort are a marriage made in heaven.

Comment: Using quicksort to sort a linked list is **evil**!  Linked lists are **meant** to be sorted with merge sort, you get `N.log(N)` time complexity with no space overhead, which is close to optimal.  Why would you use quicksort?  If it is a requirement, allocate an array of pointers, store the list element addresses into it, use the C library `qsort()` and relink the elements in the array order.  By the way, some C libraries implement `qsort` with a merge sort algorithm to avoid pathological cases.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Also, your problems aren't with quicksort. They are just linked list problems. Make sure you have a good understanding of linked lists first before trying to build on them.

Comment: unfortunately i have to use lists :(

Comment: You are not overwriting the value of `next` for the first element that you add to a new list. You should set it to `NULL`.

Comment: There's no practical reason to use lists. Presumably your design requirements are that you need to sort the list. So sort the list with an algorithm that works great with lists, like mergesort. Mergesort also has benefits like stability.

Comment: @Meowzen: *unfortunately i have to use lists :(* : that is not an unreasonable requirement, but are you also required to use quicksort?

Comment: yes, i can't get around using quicksort with a list, it's a school assignment

Comment: @Meowzen: your code had real problems.  I posted an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is an assignment, so you have to implement quicksort on a list.
Looking at your code, there are some problems that prevent proper behavior:

- in the `partition` function, you allocate a dummy `list_element` for the `pivot` for no obvious purpose and never free it, unless it is a side effect of `concatenate` which you did not post.
- in the `partition` function, you iterate to the next item with `tmp = tmp->next;`, but `tmp` was inserted at the front of one of the sublists, so its next element is not what you expect.
- in `qsortlist`, you call `init_list` with uninitialized list pointers.
- the semantics of `concatenate` are non obvious, is is supposed to allocate the `list` it returns?  When would you free that?

I implemented a simple partition, using the first element as pivot. I use 2 utility functions:

- `list_take_first(list)` to remove the first element of a list and return it,
- `list_append(list, element)` to push a `list_element` and all its chain at the end of a list.

I merged `concatenate` into the `qsort_list` function.

The code is quite simple, does not allocate memory, but recurses deeply for the pathological case where the list is already sorted.  It is easy to improve it by selecting the pivot at the middle of the list, or randomly, or by checking for sorted sublists.  You can also try to avoid recursing on the larger sublist, as you would for the array `qsort` but it is somewhat tricky.  You could also pass a comparison function to `qsortlist` and `partition` to implement different sort orders.

```
list_element *list_take_first(list *mylist) {
    list_element *le = mylist->first;
    if (le != NULL) {
        mylist->first = le->next;
        le->next = NULL;
        if (mylist->first == NULL) {
            mylist->last = NULL;
        }
    }
    return le;
}

void list_append(list *mylist, list_element *le) {
    if (le) {
        if (mylist->first == NULL) {
            mylist->first = le;
        } else {
            mylist->last->next = le;
        }
        while (le->next) {
            le = le->next;
        }
        mylist->last = le;
    }
}

list_element *partition(list *input, list *left, list *right) {
    /* simplistic partitioning: use first element as pivot */
    list_element *pivot = list_take_first(input);

    if (pivot != NULL) {
        list_element *tmp;
        while ((tmp = list_take_first(input)) != NULL) {
            if (tmp->data.anzahl >= pivot->data.anzahl) {
                list_append(right, tmp);
            } else {
                list_append(left, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    return pivot;
}

void qsort_list(list *mylist) {
    if (mylist->first != mylist->last) {
        list left, right;
        init_list(&left);
        init_list(&right);
        list_element *pivot = partition(mylist, &left, &right);
        qsort_list(&left);
        qsort_list(&right);
        list_append(mylist, left.first);
        list_append(mylist, pivot);
        list_append(mylist, right.first);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! i had to tweak the code a bit so the rigid online test would accept it but it worked out in the end :)